# Samsung Galaxy 5 gmail password

Tags: google-account

How do I get to my gmail password on Samsung Galaxy 5.  I needed to change
the password on other devices and need to change on phone
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your Gmail account is not tied to a certain device- it is universal across all Google services. You can change your password in your Google account settings. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/41078?hl=en